# How to integrate web app with SAP EWM RF functions

Tags: html, web-applications, progressive-web-apps, sap-erp

For a project I need to connect to a SAP ECC EWM (Enterprise Warehouse Mgt) system and trigger RF (Radio Frequency) functions in the SAP ECC instance. I have been reading up on how to do this and I think the best approach would be to expose the RF transactions in SAP EWM via ITSMobile and let the web app that I am creating communicate via ITSMobile hence triggering those RF functions in the SAP instance. From what I have been reading ITSMobile can generate some simple HTML pages and my web app should be able to trigger the functions exposed on those HTML pages, hence kicking off SAP transactions.

Does this approach make sense? If so, how can the external app communicate best with the simple HTML pages published via SAP ITSmobile?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question depends entirely on the version of EWM you are using and your technology stack. I would say that ITSmobile is entirely legacy at this point and nobody should be actively developing on it. ITSmobile was first released for Netweaver 2004. If you're still running a bunch of legacy Netweaver instances and have no desire to upgrade them, you could use ITSmobile.

If you're using a current version of EWM, such as 9.x, I'd encourage you to use more modern technologies. ECC might not be capable of using these modern technologies, but EWM certainly can and you can always have a mixed deployment.

First of all, do you even need to develop your own web app? Why not just use Fiori? The Fiori client exists for Android/IOS, so you can easily utilize SAP from any mobile device. We've successfully deployed Fiori client on Android devices to perform stock take, which is a much higher ROI than developing a custom app.

If you still want to develop your own app, then you can make RFC calls to EWM/ECC as you like with the SAP Netweaver RFC Library. There are bindings for many languages, such as C/C++, Java, .NET, Node.js, PHP, Python, etc. The other option is to use OData.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. Preferred option for us would be OData. The question then would be, are there default services in EWM already? It is a new version. Creating OData services yourselve could be a bit cumbersome. Else Java in combination with RFC calls would be the option.

Comment: Here's a YouTube video with the link to the slides in the video description that discusses the options for OData development -- https://youtu.be/SkfXkamR5nY -- The video is kind of old. However, the old method of exposing services as OData is a simple mapping exercise. This SAP Press book may be more helpful -- https://www.sap-press.com/abap-restful-programming-model_4988/